# How can be drwa pie chart in Ipad?

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode4

I want to draw dynamic Pie Chart in Ipad which takes values from database .
Please suggest the way to draw chart ...

Comment: Use the graphics APIs. When you get stuck on something specific, come back and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) for specifics on drawing with iOS. Also note, your view won't be taking things from a database. A controller object will get the data from the database, hold it, and tell your view to display it. The view then draws itself to represent the data its controller told it to. This is [MVC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html) 101.